# Python convert string of date tuples to list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a variable in .ini file which is list of tuples with date format. I would like to use the same in for loop but getting errors

Sample INI file

```
[VALUES]
date_range=[(2019-01-01,2019-12-31),(2020-01-01,2020-01-31),(2020-02-01,2020-02-28)]
```

script

```
import configparser
import ast

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config_file.ini')
date_range = config.get('VALUES','date_range')
print("Date Range - "+date_range)

for tuple_val in date_range:
    print("Tuple value - "+ tuple_val)
    start,end = tuple_val
    print("Start date - "+start+" and End date -"+ end)
```

Above gives below error, As it seems like date_range value is considering as a string when read from .ini file.

```
Date Range - [(2019-01-01,2019-12-31),(2020-01-01,2020-01-31),(2020-02-01,2020-02-28)]
Tuple - [
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample.py", line 236, in <module>
    for_loop()
File "sample.py", line 205, in for_loop
    start,end = tuple_val
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I have tried to convert that with ast.literal_eval() but getting invalid token error. Any help to acheive the desired reesult is much appreciated.

```
date_range = ast.literal_eval(config.get('VALUES','date_range'))
```

Comment: How are you getting data from the ini file?

Comment: Are you having trouble with reading the .ini file? Your initial date_range is already a list of tuples. What does the string look like?

Comment: Hi.. Let me edit the post to have clear idea with sample script

Comment: @Manimaran Do you have the option of changing the format of the string in the ini file, or do you have to work with what you have?

Answer (score 1):

The individual items in your `date_range` will need to be enclosed in quotes (e.g.
`"2019-01-01"`) before `literal_eval` can treat them as strings.

If it is not possible to change your ini file to do this, then you can use a regexp substitution to add them after you have read them in.

For example:

```
import re

...

date_range_s = re.sub('\(\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*\)', r'("\1","\2")',
                      config.get('VALUES','date_range'))

date_range = ast.literal_eval(date_range_s)
```

Example of the string `date_range_s`, following this substitution:

```
>>> print(date_range_s)
[("2019-01-01","2019-12-31"),("2020-01-01","2020-01-31"),("2020-02-01","2020-02-28")]
```

The rest of your code should work as-is, and gives:

```
Start date - 2019-01-01 and End date - 2019-12-31
Start date - 2020-01-01 and End date - 2020-01-31
Start date - 2020-02-01 and End date - 2020-02-28
```

This regexp will also ignore any spaces around the items, so that if you have for example `(2019-01-01, 2019-12-31)` then that is not a problem and the space will not end up forming part of the strings.

However, note that this regexp does not test whether there are quotes present already, so if you *both* supply the strings in the config file and *also* use the regexp substitution, then you will break it again.  Do one or the other.

Note also that this is not a general solution for n-element tuples. It is specifically for the 2-element ones that you have here.

Comment: Thanks @alani.. this worked.. I have permission to edit the ini file and enclosing the items with double quotes have worked.

Comment: @Manimaran, If you feel that above answer helped you, you could [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution,

```
from ast import literal_eval

# convert into valid string's by adding appropriate quotes
date_range = (
    config.get('VALUES','date_range').replace("(", "('").replace(")", "')")
)

# [('2019-01-01,2019-12-31'),('2020-01-01,2020-01-31'),('2020-02-01,2020-02-28')]

date_range = literal_eval(date_range)

for d in date_range:
    start_date, end_date = d.split(",")
    # print(start_date, end_date)
```